# How to pull latest artifacts from nexus using jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, nexus, cicd

How to dynamically retrieve the latest artifacts from Nexus using a Jenkins pipeline? Currently, when downloading an artifact, I have to manually provide the URL for that specific artifact. I explored solutions on Google and came across the idea of utilizing the Nexus REST API. However, I am struggling to understand how to implement this approach effectively.